# How to instantiate a Transformer in JUNG2 with Scala and Ints as vertices?

Tags: scala, jung

I am trying to create my own `Transformer` for shape and size of nodes in a visualization with [JUNG2](http://jung.sourceforge.net/).

However, I keep running into typing problems. I narrowed down my problem to the following example.

`PluggableRenderContext` [in JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/site/jung-visualization/xref/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/PluggableRenderContext.html) does a simple instantiation of `ConstantTransformer`, where V is the vertex type:

```
protected Transformer<V,Shape> vertexShapeTransformer = 
    new ConstantTransformer(
    new Ellipse2D.Float(-10,-10,20,20));
```

However, if I do my own instantiation in Scala like so

```
val vertexShapeTransformer: Transformer[Int, Shape] =
  new ConstantTransformer(new Ellipse2D.Float(-10,-10,20,20));
```

I get a typing error:

```
type mismatch;
found: org.apache.commons.collections15.functors.ConstantTransformer[java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Float]
required: org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer[Int,java.awt.Shape]"
```

As far as I understand, the types are conceptually compatible: `ConstantTransformer` is-a `Transformer[Object, Shape]` and `Ellipse2D` is-a `Shape`.

I assume it boils down to the fact that Scala's `Int` is not an `Object`. I cannot find a solution for this problem, though, but cannot imagine that this whole part of the library is rendered unusable as a result.

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to give scala a little help with the types. I'm not sure if this will work but you could try typing the `ConstantTransformer`:

```
  val vertexShapeTransformer: Transformer[Int, Shape] =
    new ConstantTransformer[Shape](new Ellipse2D.Float(-10,-10,20,20))
```

**UPDATE**

This should work, the type that you can pass to Transformer is anything up to Integer (not Int):

```
  val vertexShapeTransformer: Transformer[_ >: Integer, Shape] =
    new ConstantTransformer(new Ellipse2D.Float(-10,-10,20,20))
```

Comment: The error remains. It says found: ConstantTransformer[Shape] required: Transformer[Int,Shape] (the type of ConstantTransformer[Shape] is Transformer[Object,Shape]). I feel this is the correct typing (i.e. as intended), just that still Scala's `Int` is not an `Object` and the implicit conversion between Scala and Java types does not work here.

Comment: Does it work if you change int to Object or something else? AnyRef?

Comment: First, it needs to be Integer not Int so we can satisfy the Object dependency, and it needs to be contravariant. Would be nice if Scala could just pick this up, but at least it's okay with Shape now.

Comment: Using `Transformer[Object, Shape]` or `Transformer[AnyRef, Shape]` does resolve compilation issues. The anonymous type you suggested also works. A quick follow-up-note. Using this to actually do something is still tricky. I figured out how to use an instance of `VertexShapeFactory` for `Int` nodes: First instantiate something like `new VertexShapeFactory[Object](new ConstantTransformer(10), new ConstantTransformer(1.0f))` (with `Object` as vertex type), then specify the type to be `Integer` as you call: `factory.getEllipse(vertex: Integer)` (`vertex` is of type `Int`).